# Sort a list of list of strings based on characters after first space

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of list of strings. I want to sort the list based on characters after the first space(alphanumeric Sort). if the characters after the first space is same,then sort by the characters before the first space

```
L2 = ["ea first qpx", "India Kashmir Equator Khidderpore", "India Kashmir Alipore" , "az0 first qpx", "India Ambati Chembur Mahavir"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where's the problem?

Comment: I think for the first case you can try regex and sorted.

`sorted(l2,key= lambda x: re.findall('\s(.)',x)[0])`

Comment: Thanks got the answer, I was not splitting the inner string so when I was x[1::], it was starting from the second character and I was getting the wrong sorting. I was doing L2.sort(key = lambda x:(x[1::],x[0])) instead it should be L2.sort(key = lambda x:(x.split()[1::],x[0]))

Answer (score 1):

Sort the inner list making use of Lambda expression in `sort()`

`L2.sort(key = lambda x  : (x.split(" ")[1].lower(), x.split(" ")[0].lower()))`

This will split the inner list by spaces and sort it on the basis of first character set after space. If first characters are same then characters present at zeroth index will be considered.

lower() is used to make sorting case insensitive. If not used then strings with uppercase characters will have higher precedence over the lowercase characters.

Examples:

````
>> L2 = ["x c t", "a a g", "c a g"]

>> L2.sort(key = lambda x : (x.split(" ")[1].lower(), x.split(" ")[0].lower()))

>> L2

['a a g', 'c a g', 'x c t']

L2 = ["ea first qpx", "India Kashmir Equator Khidderpore", "India Kashmir Alipore" , "az0 first qpx", "India Ambati Chembur Mahavir"]

>> L2.sort(key = lambda x : (x.split(" ")[1].lower(), x.split(" ")[0].lower()))

>> L2

['India Ambati Chembur Mahavir', 'az0 first qpx', 'az0 first qpx', 'India Kashmir Equator Khidderpore', 'India Kashmir Alipore']```
````

Comment: Have updated the answer to consider the scenario where first characters can be same. Hope it helps. Kindly upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This works and returns
**sorted new list**
`['Ambati Chembur Mahavir', 'Kashmir Alipore', 'Kashmir Equator Khidderpore', 'first qpx', 'first qpx']`

Here is the code:

```
L2 = ["ea first qpx", "India Kashmir Equator Khidderpore", "India Kashmir Alipore" , "az0 first qpx", "India Ambati Chembur Mahavir"] 


def sortListAfterSpaceClean(myList):
    newList = []
    for i, val in enumerate(myList):
        # create a list of the characters
        z = list(val)
        for j, jVal in enumerate(z):
            if jVal == " ":
                # we want the rest of the string
                lenOfString = len(val) - j - 1
                restOfString = val[-lenOfString:]
                newList.append(restOfString)
                break



    print('the old list:')    
    print(myList)
    print('the new list:')
    print(newList)
    print('sorted new list')
    newList.sort()
    print(newList)

    return newList



sortListAfterSpaceClean(L2)
```

Feel free to edit & comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

`def sortListAfterSpaceSplit(myList):
    newList = []
    for val in myList:
        # split the string

        s = val.split(' ', 1)
        newList.append(s[1])
        newList.sort()
    return newList`